# NoMethodError during Stripe integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, marketplace

I'm building a marketplace and am using stripe to split payments between the seller and us. I get a nomethoderror when sending the bank token to stripe.

My listing_controller creates the recipient as the person creating the listing and gets the token from stripe:

```
Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
token = params[:stripeToken]

recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
    :name => current_user.name,
    :type => "individual",
    :bank_account => token
    )

current_user.recipient = recipient.id
```

The above code gets the bank token from stripe and assigns it to the seller. i can see the token in the database.

My orders controller defines the seller as the user who listed the item and tells stripe to transfer 80% of price to the seller:

```
@seller = @listing.userid

transfer = Stripe::Transfer.create(
  :amount => (@listing.price * 80).floor, 
  :currency => "usd",
  :recipient => @seller.recipient
  )
```

I get a NoMethodError on the last line - recipient => @seller.recipient.

Any thoughts on what the problem may be? I'm on rails 4.

Comment: What do the schema and model for a listing look like? Without knowing that, it appears you're expecting an object (calling `recipient` on `@seller`) while having an integer or string (`@listing.userid`).

Comment: hi, thanks, sorry for not giving enough info. i figured it out. i had to change the line to :recipient => @order.seller.recipient. I was following a tutorial that used the code as posted in my question but for some reason it didn't work for me. I had the same models, etc as in the tutorial but I am on Windows and the tutorial was on a Mac. Not sure if that was the reason for the difference.